# Algorithm for computing an approximate value of $\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: number-theory, pi

I seek a simple algorithm or function that will produce an approximate value for $\sqrt{\pi}$, but none that begin with the actual value of $\pi$, then derive the root via approximation.

This is very specific. What (known?) natural function will produce this number without the usual methods of deriving $\pi$?

There may be an answer to this close at hand, but historical perspective is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Why the vote to close I wonder?

Comment: Use your favorite numerical root-finding algorithm to approximate
 the unique solution of $\sin(x^2)=0$ in the interval $1 < x < 2$?  Numerically integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$?  Are those the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: $\sqrt\pi=\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg).$ See [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more information.

Comment: Aside: do you have a particular reason? I suspect your motivation for such a thing is misguided.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a
formula of Ramanujan
for
$\sqrt{\frac{\pi e^x}{2x}}
$:
https://oeis.org/wiki/A_remarkable_formula_of_Ramanujan

Put $x=1$ or $x=2$
to get
$\sqrt{\pi}$
as the sum of a continued fraction
and a series,
both of which can be
evaluated iteratively.

Of course
$e$ or $e^{1/2}$
has to be evaluated also,
but these too
can be done iteratively.

Comment: I am aware of several numerical "engines" to derive the actual value.

Comment: ** I just suffered a small crash** so bear with the interruption. I need to clarify. Pi as a constant has many uses, but most strikingly so for anything circular or spheroidal. I have yet to find such an affiliation for the square root of Pi. Where is it a needed "tool" to define some aspect or other. Somewhere the function of Pi will not accomplish. I have this interest as our research group may have stumbled upon such a function. If there is nothing new under the sun, someone else has already done something with it long before we came along. WAH

Comment: @WAH:  While that is a sensible question (what applications are there for $\sqrt{\pi}$, it is much broader than the Question posed above (how to approximate $\sqrt{\pi}$ without first approximating $\pi$).  Does the body of your Question stand in need of editing?

Comment: Actually, I am interested in both.